# Why a restored stsadm Site is'nt showing images and styles?

Tags: stsadm, restore

I've a site which I migrated with `stsadm -o restore -url urlto site - filename file.dat`. Restored to a new web application in the production machine.

The development machine does not use host header ( instead is accessed via port 31011)

- Both are windows 2003.
- Both have the same Moss 2007 versions (with SP2,  12.0.0.6421 )
- Both have the language pack spanish and language pack service pack 2.
- Both sites have windows authentication.

Then I changed the site collection administrator and could logon successfully, but  is displaying the whole site without styles and images. It's odd I've now 2 days without success.

Plus,  after hitting the enter key to make the browsers request the page, it asks me the credentials so many times and each time it's displaying an empty white box instead of the actual image.

All this tried with site collection admin.

Already tried this:

- Site  stsadm restore in the same development machine ( succeeded)
- Currently trying to restore in another site
- The IIS logs shows 200 results once the request is done OK
- MOSS logs shows something weird related to permissions:

> **02/09/2010 19:38:11.57  w3wp.exe (0x2630)                           0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     6t8g    Verbose     Looking up typical site http://ebiblioteca in web
>   application SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - eBilioteca80
>   Parent=SPWebService.    02/09/2010 19:38:11.57    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     6t8h    Verbose     Found typical site /
>   (87ebf90c-5f0a-462c-976a-11d792342593) in web application
>   SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - eBilioteca80 Parent=SPWebService.
>   02/09/2010 19:38:11.61    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000005,
>   have 0x00000000     02/09/2010 19:38:11.61    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000005,
>   have 0x00000000     02/09/2010 19:38:11.61    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000015,
>   have 0x00000000     02/09/2010 19:38:11.61    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000005,
>   have 0x00000000     02/09/2010 19:38:11.61    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000015,
>   have 0x00000000     02/09/2010 19:38:11.61    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000005,
>   have 0x00000000     02/09/2010 19:38:11.61    w3wp.exe (0x2630)
>     0x1DD8  Windows SharePoint Services     General
>     8xfr    Verbose     PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00000015,
>   have 0x00000000
>   **

Any ideas would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things here:

- Using backup/restore to move a site between environments is only supported under specific circumstances. For publishing sites, you need SP2 and the April 2009 Cumulative Update or later (not sure without checking version numbers if you have this). [Stefan discusses this for publishing sites here](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan%5Fgossner/archive/2009/05/01/red-is-green-up-is-down-and-the-unsupported-suddenly-becomes-supported.aspx), but I'm not sure how this applies to other types of site unfortunately - they might be supported also.
- If this isn't the issue and all your paths are correct, it sounds like an authentication issue. Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check for 401s on the CSS and image files.

If you really are getting access denied on these files, what happens if you try to browse to these files directly in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the 401.1 unauthorized error every time i try to  directly access the images from the browser...

I didn't set a theme  but  one image ( the only one that I put with Sharepoint Designer )  is missing, it is in looking  at _themes subfolder. 

BUt, the rest of the look & feel, the style, seems to be missing and I guess that it'd be returning a 401.1 

Again, this is while logged on as site collection administrator. 

My site has enabled the feature " publishing", and has the default theme and default moss css. 

Please help !!! 

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I have another comment, is stsadm -o backup the best way to move my site from one farm to another????

Comment: A couple of things to consider:

- Where are your images/CSS files stored?
- Do the paths look correct i.e. they relate to the current farm/current site?
- If they are stored in SharePoint, are they approved/published?

In terms of moving sites between farms, common options are STSADM backup, STSADM export and a tool I wrote called the SharePoint Contet Deployment Wizard. The latter is basically the same as STSADM export but allows you more control over the export/import process (e.g. there's an option to allow you to keep the same IDs, which is important in some scenarios).

Answer (score 2):

Did you create the modifications and styles using SharePoint Designer?  They should have been restored during the content db restoration if so.  Are the CSS and images stored in sharepoint libraries?  If they are then your pages may be referencing broken links for the CSS and image locations.  You may need to update these pages with SharePoint Designer.

If you were storing the images and styles on the old server's file system you may need to copy them to the new server and verify their paths are correct.

Also verify that your alternate access mappings are the same on both servers.